# zsh: trouble batch-renaming files with zmv

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to mass rename the files from one extension to another (background: use haml instead of erb in my rails app). I get following output when issuing rename command:

```
% zmv '**/*.erb' $1.haml    
zmv: error(s) in substitution:
app/views/l/links/index.html.erb and app/views/index/index.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/l/links/new.html.erb and app/views/l/links/index.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/l/links/show.html.erb and app/views/l/links/new.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/l/links/stats.html.erb and app/views/l/links/show.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb and app/views/l/links/stats.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/u/profiles/_form.erb and app/views/layouts/application.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/u/profiles/edit.html.erb and app/views/u/profiles/_form.erb both map to .haml
app/views/u/profiles/show.html.erb and app/views/u/profiles/edit.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/u/user_sessions/new.html.erb and app/views/u/profiles/show.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/u/users/_form.erb and app/views/u/user_sessions/new.html.erb both map to .haml
app/views/u/users/new.html.erb and app/views/u/users/_form.erb both map to .haml
app/views/u/users/show.html.erb and app/views/u/users/new.html.erb both map to .haml
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction of fixing this?

Comment: do you want an answer to, *how do I do this with `zmv`?* or an answer to, *how can mass rename files from one extension to another?*

Comment: @xenoterracide - yes ,)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you really want is something like this:

```
% zmv '(**/)(*).erb' '$1/$2.haml'
#      ^$1  ^$2
```

You need to use the parenthesis to create match groups, and you create a match group for the path to the file, and then a match group for the file name. Also, you need to make sure the second argument is also in single-quotes for zmv.

Also, it's a really good idea to test zmv commands with '-n' before you run them (-n will tell you what will be renamed, but not actually rename anything.)

Comment: Unfortunately (at least up to zsh 4.3.10), `(**)/` matches exactly one directory level, i.e., `**` loses its special meaning and is equivalent to `*`. So this command works but doesn't have the intended meaning.

Comment: @Gilles: Yeah, I had it right the first time, and then I edited it because I'm stupid. However, (**/) works properly, so I'm going to update the post to what I had originally so that it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `zsh` what `$1` refers to. There are two possibilities:

- Use parentheses around parts of the source pattern that you want to use. For example, in `zmv '(*)/(*).erb' '$1/$2.haml'`, '$1' means what is matched by the first `*` and `$2` means what is matched by the second `$2`.

  [**EDIT** (thanks to [clee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/995/zsh-trouble-batch-renaming-files-with-zmv/1001#1001) for pointing out that `(**/)` works)] Parentheses are a little awkward to use with multiple directory levels. If you write `(**)`, the double asterisk loses its special meaning (only a single directory level is matched). And you mostly can't use `/` inside parentheses, so `(**/*)` is not a valid pattern. However, the special case `(**/)` works, so you can write `zmv '(**/)(*).erb' '$1$2.haml'`.
- Use the `-w` option, in which case each `$N` corresponds to the text matched by the *N*th wildcard in the source pattern. For example, `zmv -w '**/*.erb' '$1/$2.haml'` does what you want.

Note that you must always use single quotes around the replacement text (or use `\$`), otherwise the `$`s are expanded by the shell before they get to the `zmv` built-in command.